# Oracle:inserting multiple rows into table by taking input from user in pl/sql program

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, sqlplus, substitution

How to insert multiple rows into table by talking input from user like
insert into tablename values(&value1,'&value2',...) using loops in pl/sql program.

some sample code is

```
begin
for i in 1..3
loop

    insert into tablename values(&value1,'&value2');
end loop;
end;
```

The above code is taking input only once, but it inserts same data into table for 3 times.

Is there any way to get different input from user for each iteration of loop.

Comment: PL/SQL is not appropriate for this task. Anyway, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**PL/SQL** is not interactive and therefore it is not suitable to take user inputs. I would suggest to provide a UI to the end user for this task. `&` is used for **substitution variable** in `SQL*Plus`.

Although it is possible in `SQL*Plus`, however, I still wonder who on earth would want to give SQL*Plus as an UI to a user.

Anyway, you would need two scripts to achieve the task, an insert script to do the insert, another script to control the user input and clean exit.

**insert.sql:**

```
INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
  ('&value'
  );
```

**control.sql:**

```
ACCEPT SELECTION PROMPT "Enter values to insert, enter 'exit' when no more values to insert :"

SET TERM OFF VERIFY OFF

COLUMN USER_MENU NEW_VALUE SCRIPT

SELECT
  CASE '&selection.'
    WHEN 'exit'
    THEN NULL
    ELSE '@insert &menu.'
  END AS user_menu
FROM dual;

SET TERM ON

@&script
```